# Python interactive shell / interpreter in the Atom editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, atom-editor, interpreter

I am programming in Python 3 and I recently found Atom editor. It looks amazing and has a great functionality. I want to ask, if there is a package or any way of having an interactive python shell in the Atom editor. And no, I am **not** looking for simple script executing package such as the [script package](https://atom.io/packages/script) or the [Hydrogen package](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen).

I need this:
[(shell.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns24e.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Which forum should I use then? I think the question is suitable for this forum.

Comment: This is not a forum, this is a question-and-answer site. It is [explicitly off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You still did not answer my question, plus I am not looking for a recommendation yet a specific solution to the problem.

Comment: Yes. **Because this is off topic**. You are asking "if there is a package or any way of having an interactive python shell in the Atom editor. "

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I used Atom. There is a package (probably several) you can install that gives you a built in bash/cmd shell, simply execute "python" from that and you'll get an interactive python shell.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Repl package that brings up a separate python shell console. I find it very useful and you can open the console for python2 or python 3.

Comment: Any chance of a link to this package?

Comment: Under the Atom menu select preferences. A window appears saying Core Settings. To the left of this windown in a narrower window with the first entry core. Scroll down in this narrow window until you see 'Install'.This brings up a new window on the right where you can load extensions.  Type in platformia-ide-terminal and hit packages button on right. This will install that package.  Exit out and restart Atom. When Atom is restarted, You should see your nrew package under packages menu.  Click that menu then click select. This should open a window in bottom of Atom window.